# REQUEST_DENIED in responce of Google Places API Request (sensor=true)

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get places around my location, using Google Places API.

Following is the code, for hitting URL for places search.

```
NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=true&key=0dp-j3dkCU_YUb97RHcbL5shmRrJ5R2y4bYz1Vw"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval: 4];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];
NSObject *id1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Which gets me the following response, in JSON Format.

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

On Searching Google Places API, It says, incorrect **sensor** parameter value is general cause for "REQUEST_DENIED". But, In my case, I am providing that, too, correct.

Any Idea where am I going wrong ??

Again, the APIKey I am using is common for the App to be develope on Android, iPhone and BlackBerry. Is that Valid ? Or, Do I need another APIKey (Specific for my iPhone App)? So, Another question is, **Can i use the same key on all three platforms ??**

Comment: I thought I'd comment just so you know someone has heard your plea! I tried the url in the documentation **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI** and that too gives a REQUEST_DENIED. I tried substituting your api key into that url and ditto - denied. The only thing your url is 'missing' from the documented example is &types and &name. I tried pretty much all the permutations I could think of but still got the DENIED.

Comment: @Damo: Thanks for trying. I appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took your URL and substituted a key that I know works, and got the expected results.  At first glance I am guessing either your copied/pasted your key incorrectly, or you have not enabled the Places API for the Project this key is associated with in the API Console.

It's important to note that each project can have different services enabled - and you must enable the Places API manually for each project you wish to use it with -- can you confirm it is enabled in the console and the key is copied accurately?

Comment: It wasn't enabled in API console. Now, it's working fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @jlivni Does the Google Places API work with a native IOS App?

Comment: @Pranav Sure it's just a REST-like API -- you can make http requests from your native app to the Places API and parse the results to display as you see fit (within the terms of service).

Answer (score 0):

This error message can also appear if you are missing required parameters.

For example, I just had a similar issue using the `/autocomplete` endpoint of the Places API.

Sending a request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&input=San, I was getting a response like this:

```
{
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Even though it looks like a permissions issue (at least to me), it turns out I was simply missing a required `sensor` parameter.