# How to find nearest point of interest using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

For an application I'm developing, I need to find the nearest bus stops using the Google Maps API. How would I accomplish this?

The place search API just returns REQUEST_DENIED, so that isn't much help.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=AIzaSyCNutXaoPSvdgAboAp7CYLZ2S5oVv_Fe7o&location=52.069858,4.291111&radius=1000&sensor=false`

http://puu.sh/zUUa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `REQUEST_DENIED` gives you a clue that your query is well-formed, but there is something invalid. If it's not the lack of the `sensor` parameter, it must be the key you provided. I don't have a key myself to test it, and Google refuses to give it saying the URL I provided is invalid... I can only suggest you to double-check your key, and maybe try with another account.

**EDIT**: Now I've managed to get my key and found your mistake: you forgot to put `https`, not `http`, in your request.

Comment: I tried https, but it made no difference. Here is the one including my API key (browser app, referer agnostic): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=AIzaSyCNutXaoPSvdgAboAp7CYLZ2S5oVv_Fe7o&location=52.069858,4.291111&radius=1000&sensor=false API console: http://puu.sh/zUUa

Comment: Try it with my new key: AIzaSyDx6XG_qYpWzpeF6rwZ7EWO9Kxriy_vzgc , which works for me. I'll delete it in 24 hours, btw. I have no clue either - the best I found at SO says to activate it at the **Services** pane: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385990/request-denied-google-maps-api-v3-places-error . Also, are you using a dedicated Places API key? That was a problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833085/request-denied-in-responce-of-google-places-api-request-sensor-true .

Comment: I've enabled it in the API console now and the graph displays traffic when I use my API key, but I still get a REQUEST_DENIED. Your key works fine.

Comment: Nevermind, generating an entirely new key fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!